# Points on a sphere - how to get the third angle

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, angle, spheres

So by the equation of a sphere

$x = x_0 + r\cdot\sin\theta\cos\phi$

$y = y_0 + r\cdot\sin\theta\sin\phi$

$z = z_0 + r\cdot\cos\theta$

I can get the three coordinates from two angles and I can get the two angles from the coordinates. However, how do I get the third angle (that I think goes around the $x$-axis)?

**EDIT**

Can I simply say that the angle between $z$ and $y$ comes from

$z=z_0+r\cos\varphi$

$y = y_0 + r\sin\varphi$

and do $\varphi = \cos^{-1}\frac{z-z_0}{r}$?

Comment: There are only 2 angles, theta and phi.

Comment: A sphere is a two-dimensional surface (as opposed to a ball), so you only need two angles. Think of the longitudes and latitudes of the Earth. (And of course, the radius supplies the third dimension needed for a coordinate system.)

Comment: I need the angle around the third axis. I have all the other data, but I need the angle around the last axis. I am coding a camera for a game and want to specify either angle in radians.

Comment: Spherical coordinates only specify a location. It says nothing about what orientation you are in. You probably want to take a look at [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Note that it is usually easier to program these things using a set of three perpendicular unit vectors, and only use the angles for input/output purposes.

Comment: I can enter the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ to get my coordinates. And I can obviously solve the system of equations for $\theta$ and $\phi$. This gives me the angles around $y$ and $z$, and it also shows when I test it in game.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates as you described them don't really naturally have a third angle. Because the plane in which the $\phi$ is chosen already depends on the $\theta$-angle. As you can see in this image from Wikipedia:

[image]

What you could do is just expand on the idea of $\theta$ which is the angle around the z-axis with the formula: $\theta = arctan(y/x)$.
This gives a simple idea for the rest, the angle around the y-axis is $arctan(x/z)$ and around the x-axis is $arccos(z/y)$.

This is the main idea, depending on the orientation you chose, you'll probably have to invert some of the fractions, but this should be the gist of it.

I know this is all somewhat handwavy, but I think Euler angles might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I understand that I have the two angles and that they describe all other three coordinates, but I guess I want to know how to transform the system of equations to have $\theta$ around the $y$-axis and $\phi$ around the $x$-axis instead then. If there is no way to compute the angle between $z$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry, I misunderstood, I'll try to figure it out. If you don't mind me asking why would need all three angles?

Comment: I am coding a second-person camera in a game and I want to be able to specify the horizontal and vertical angle to set where the camera should be. Although I realize now that I probably need some transformation on the $x$-axis since I actually want it to rotate vertically around the $x$-axis from the camera's perspective after rotating around the $y$-axis (up). I will look at euler angles.